# String split without first element

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to use a `strsplit` to rename some items in a list. Specifically I'd like to exclude the first element, and them collapse the rest of them back together. The main problem that I'm having is that the strings are not all the same length.

Dummy set:

```
dumb <- c(
  "title_use",
  "title_use_full",
  "title_use_full_info"
)

sapply(strsplit(dumb, "_"), head, -1)
```

Obviously this doesn't work as intended. Is there a way to exclude the first element(s) without needing to know how many chunks it will be broken into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tail` instead of `head` to exclude the first part and paste the rest

```
sapply(strsplit(dumb, "_"),function(x) paste0(tail(x, -1), collapse = "_"))
#[1] "use"           "use_full"      "use_full_info"
```

However, you don't need to split the string, you can use `sub` to remove everything until first underscore.

```
sub(".*?_", "", dumb)
#[1] "use"           "use_full"      "use_full_info"
```

Or doing it other way around, extract everything after 1st underscore

```
sub(".*?_(.*)", "\\1", dumb)
```

Comment: This is great, the use of `sub` is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

`regexpr` will give the position of first `_` and then `substring` can subset `dumb` from that position to the end which is given by `nchar`. `substring` is vectorized so no need for loop.

```
substring(dumb, regexpr("_", dumb) + 1, nchar(dumb))
#[1] "use"           "use_full"      "use_full_info"
```